# How can I clear the stl_load_errors table in Redshift?

Tags: batch-processing, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to clear out the contents of the `stl_load_errors` table in Amazon's Redshift?

I am running batch processes to `COPY` into Redshift and it would be convenient if I could view the entire stl_load_errors in one go without having to filter by a time range.

When I attempt to `DELETE  FROM stl_load_errors`, I get "*ERROR: cannot delete from a system table*"

When I attempt to `TRUNCATE stl_load_errors`, I get "*ERROR: permission denied: "stl_load_errors" is a system catalog*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, you can't delete from that table.

It's worth noting that Redshift will automatically clear down that table over time, i.e., it doesn't hold *all* load errors forever.

Answer (score 5):

You can't delete from stl_load_errors but if you use COPY query from S3 you can filter the SELECT from stl_load_errors using filename.
for example:
`select * from stl_load_errors where filename like 's3://BUCKET/PREFIX_OF_PATH%'`

The stl_load_errors will delete old data (usually a week old), so you don't need to worry about disk space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get all errors for your copy command.

```
SELECT err.userid,
       err.process,
       err.recordtime,
       err.pid,
       err.errcode,
       err.file,
       err.linenum,
       err.context,
       err.error
FROM stl_error err,
     stv_recents rec
WHERE rec.pid=err.pid
  AND rec.status='running'
  AND rec.query LIKE 'COPY%';
```

Please edit `copy%` in above query part as per your command.